# Storage aggregation is not combining like I would expect

Tags: grafana, metrics, graphite, graphite-carbon, whisper

I'm not getting expected results with some metrics I am tracking in Graphite and displaying in Grafana.

For metric like:

```
bitbucket.commits-per-user.username1.count
bitbucket.commits-per-user.username2.count
```

I have a retention policy like:

```
[default_bitbucket]
pattern = ^bitbucket\.
retentions = 1m:30d,1h:2y
```

I am pulling the data from an api, summarizing by the minute that the commit occurred for the user and adding it at with a timestamp of that minute (rounded down to the whole minute).

The storage-aggregation policy I am using is this:

```
[count_bitbucket]
pattern = ^bitbucket.*\.count$
xFilesFactor = 0
aggregationMethod = sum
```

I would expect that, once the timeframe exceeds 30 days, and I were running the metric with the function:

```
summarize(1d,sum,true)
```

, I would see commits per hour for whatever time period. However, It seems to be reporting significantly less per day once I move beyond 30 days.

[image: These should be similar]

Is there anything I am doing obviously wrong?

Could there be a problem if I don't add metrics for zeros on minutes when there are no commits?

I really appreciate any guidance - I'm fairly new to graphite.